# What is the catalyst necessary to transform into a titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

At first I thought that you must hurt yourself in order to transform into a titan.

But later,

> We see that Reiner and Bertholdt transformed without self harm, because they transformed immediately after Mikasa cut them in episode 6 of season 2 (episode 31 on Crunchyroll).

Also, thinking back, Eren did not commit self harm when he transformed from within the belly of the titan in season 1.

We see also that sometimes Eren is hurt and he still cannot transform, even though the injury *was* self induced. What **exactly** must take place in order to transform?

Comment: being injured is sufficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Attack on Titan [wikia](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_the_Titans)

> In order to transform, a human with the power of the Titans must
>   suffer an injury that draws blood (often self-harm) while having a
>   solid goal or belief in mind at the moment of injury.

You can check when Eren was training with Levi in the castle, he discovered that only injury is not sufficient.

*when he transformed from within the belly of the titan in season 1.*
In that scene you can find that all the above conditions are met.
1. Eren was injured( his hand was cut)
2. He has solid goal in mind. i.e to defeat the titan

You can read more cases/conditions in the wiki link I provided

Answer (score 0):

in season 1 epi 23  annie put a metal ring before she transform into a titan, so yea i think it does required a metal to activate a titan form and in epi 19 while eren is eating he's spoon drop a remember something and once he got the metal he transform into a titan without any reason or being hurt

Answer (score -1):

I just want to say that, this might not hold, but the way I saw it when he transformed in the belly of the titan was that maybe he transformed because he wouldn't have gotten his arm bitten off if it weren't for his self-sacrifice. This was my explanation of how that counted as self harm.